Not sure which permission I am lacking - Docker Desktop - Permission Denied Error
Docker permission error. I have been trying to run a Docker environment repository using Docker desktop. Below is the error I am receiving. I had many errors on the way, but with proxy settings I am able to overcome them. The only part now is APK not being installed due to permission issue.
Docker File:
FROM golang:1.18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/org/repo
COPY . .

RUN go mod init
RUN go build -o deploy/api-status

FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/org/repo/deploy/  ./deploy
RUN sed -ie "s/https/http/g" /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk add tzdata

ENTRYPOINT ./deploy/api-status

Error:
#51 [api-status stage-1 5/5] RUN apk add tzdata
#51 0.671 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#51 1.544 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#51 3.828 (1/1) Installing tzdata (2024a-r1)
#51 4.120 ERROR: tzdata-2024a-r1: Permission denied
#51 4.126 1 error; 8 MiB in 14 packages

Error without Proxy:
0.566 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
1.019 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
1.023 WARNING: updating and opening http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main: Permission      denied
1.353 WARNING: updating and opening http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community: Permission denied
1.353 ERROR: unable to select packages:
1.353   tzdata (no such package):
1.353     required by: world[tzdata]

